# Difficulty with recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion

while reading the book eloquent Javascript and I came across this recursive function I can't quite get my head around. The function takes a number as a argument and return the string solution of how that number can be reached by either adding 5 or multiplying that number by 1. Here the code:

```
function findSolution(target) {
    function find(start, history) {

        if (start == target)
            return history;
        else if (start > target)
            return null;
        else
            return find(start + 5, "(" + history + " + 5) ") ||
                find(start * 3, "(" + history + " * 3) ");
    }
    return find(1, "1");
}
console.log(findSolution(24));
// ! (((1 * 3) + 5) * 3)
```

I especially don't get the part in the else statement that it can return different functions using the || operator. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It returns the *result* of different functions. If the first find returns null, it tries the second find and returns that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `||` operator evaluates its left operand. If it's truthy, the value of the expression is that value; otherwise it evaluates the right operand and the value of the expression is that value. The `return` statement then returns that value.

Put another way, the statement:

```
return <expression1> || <expression2>
```

is equivalent to:

```
var temp = <expression1>;
if (temp) {
    return temp;
} else {
    return <expression2>;
}
```

You can use a series of `||` operators, e.g

```
return <expr1> || <expr2> || <expr3> | ...;
```

It will return the first truthy value in the series, and not execute any of the remaining expressions.

So in your function, it first tries `find(start + 5, "(" + history + " + 5) ")`. If that returns a truthy value, it's returned by the function; if not, it then tries `find(start * 3, "(" + history + " * 3) ")` and returns that value.

Answer (score 0):

The || operand is the OR operator and it operates from the leftmost operand; for instance

```
var x = 2 || 5;
```

In simple English, it means x = 2 OR 5, but the javascript interpreter just select the first value from the left that is valid... in this case x will be equal to 2.

However, if

```
var x = 5 || 2
```

x will be equal to 5; but if we have an "invalid" input at the left hand that returns false when cohesion, e.g null and undefined; Javascript take the next value that is "valid" or truthy for instance:

```
var x = null || 2
```

will make x = 2;

Also :

```
function find(){ 
    return(5/'a') 
}
function find2(){
    return 12 
}
var x = find() || find2()
```

will make x equal 12 because 5/'a' is NaN(not a number) and is cohesed to false .

So in your recursion example :

```
find(start + 5, "(" + history + " + 5) ") ||
            find(start * 3, "(" + history + " * 3) ");
```

if

```
find(start + 5, "(" + history + " + 5) ")
```

is evaluated and "start" is greater than "target" (line 6 of your code) then null is return and

```
find(start * 3, "(" + history + " * 3) ")
```

is evaluated.